# Default user image in user account menu!

Tags: theming, 8, media

I am trying to add a default image to render in the user account menu when the user does not have an image.

CODE:

```
function nestle_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if($variables['menu_name'] == "account") {
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $name = $variables['user']->getUsername();
    $picture = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
    $picture = $user->user_picture->view('large');
    $variables['items']['user.page']['title'] = $name;
    $variables['items']['user.page']['picture'] = $picture;
  }
}
```

What I did so far, is that I changed the "account" menu link to name of the logged in user and I added the picture of the user in the variables array so that I can render it using twig, The problem is I want to check when the $picture variable is empty ( ie: user has no photo ) it should render a default image from a URL.

PS: I am using Drupal 8, and this code is in the .theme file

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a user picture exists this way:

```
if (!$user->user_picture->isEmpty()) {
  $picture = file_create_url($file->getFileUri());
  $picture = $user->user_picture->view('large');
} else {
  $picture_field = \Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', 'user_picture');
  $default_image = $picture_field->getSetting('default_image');
  $file = \Drupal::entityManager()->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
  $picture = $file->getFileUri();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Function:

```
function custom_ImageURL() {

  $imageURL = NULL;

  $imageFieldName = // However you're getting your field name.

  // Check the field exists.
  if (!empty(FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', $imageFieldName))) {

    // Check there is a primary image.
    if ($user->$imageFieldName->entity) {

      $imageURL = $user->$imageFieldName->entity->url();

    }
    // No primary image, check for default image.
    elseif (FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', $imageFieldName)
      ->getSetting('default_image')['uuid']) {

      $imageGetSettings = FieldConfig::loadByName('user', 'user', $imageFieldName)
        ->getSetting('default_image');

      $imageURI = Drupal::service('entity.repository')
        ->loadEntityByUuid('file', $imageGetSettings['uuid'])
        ->getFileUri();

      $imageURL = file_create_url($imageURI);

    }

  }

  return $imageURL;

}
```

To load with an image style replace `$imageURL = ...` with:

```
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');

$imageStyleURL = $style->buildUrl($user
  ->$imageFieldName->entity->uri->value);

$imageURL = $imageStyleURL;
```

Then in whatever preprocess function you need:

```
function hook_preprocess_menu(&$variables, $hook) {

  $imageURL = custom_ImageURL();

}
```

I have found checking if the field exists via `FieldConfig::loadByName()` produces fewer use case errors than `->isEmpty` or `->isEmpty()`.

Then you can compare against `entity` existing for the primary value. The default value is stored in field settings array.